# how to hook plugin function into custom function in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

In wordpress I am trying to use Advance Custom Field Plugin's function into my own function.
I have added

`add_action( 'post_link_resource_lessonplans_shortcode', 'the_field' );`

before my function and into my function. I have use

`do_action('the_field');`

but there is no result i can found on the browser so any help? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the_field($field_name) directly in your custom function.
Or

```
if(function_exists('the_field')){
    the_field($field_name);
}
```

Anyway the_field function needs at least one parameter.